# How to isolate a specific nested value in complex DOM element string?

Tags: php

I'm looking to return the value that is nested in the an element containing an href value with `john` in it (in this example, it is `7 goals`). Any help?

```
<?php
$html_string = '<div class="foo"><a href="../john-smith.html"><span>7 goals</span></a></div><div class="foo2"><h2><a href="../adam-green.html">8 points</a></h2></div>';
echo $isolated_character;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a variant, you Can use class DomDocument and its Xpath

```
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html_string);
$x = new DomXpath($d);
echo $res = $x->evaluate('string(//a[contains(@href, "john")]/span)'); // 7 goals
```

Comment: While this may work for this particular example, it doesn't answer my question. I need to search the string for an `href` value that contains "john", and return the value in the nested `<span>`.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!